# when upgrading should i delete all files AND all folders in templates_c directory?

Tags: upgrade

I am following the wordpress upgrade procedure here:
https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/wordpress/

the instrucutions say to clear cached files by removing all files in the templates_c directory.

I have a  subdirectory en_US within the templates_c directory which has many further subdirectories.  Am i supposed to delete these too?  or just the files in the template_c director itself?

many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes also the en_US subfolder. Actually **especially** that folder, since that's where the precompiled files get stored.

You can also use the menu option under Administer -> System Settings -> Cleanup Caches, which will do it for you.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  I've just tried Cleanup Caches, but it seems not to have removed the subfolders.  so just to confirm - -I can remove everything in the templates_c folder?

Comment: It did delete it, but then as soon as the page reloaded it would have created it again to cache that page's template. You'll see there would have been less sub-subfolders. But yes can delete everything.

Comment: thanks - upgrade complete and all seems to have gone smoothly :)